# When and why did Putin stop using his famously long tables for meetings?

Tags: russian-federation, vladimir-putin

Putin [famously used](https://www.forbes.com/sites/dereksaul/2022/02/15/putins-long-tables-explained-why-he-puts-some-leaders-including-germanys-scholz-at-an-extreme-distance/?sh=54e4fa8470fb) very long tables for meetings, such as during the [meeting with Macron](https://www.dw.com/en/ukraine-crisis-putin-says-macron-made-realistic-proposals/a-60684622) in February 2022:

[image]

or with his own military ([in Feb](https://www.euractiv.com/section/global-europe/news/outcry-in-the-west-as-putin-orders-nuclear-alert/))

[image]

However it looks like he switched to using normal tables, as evidenced by [this photo](http://kremlin.ru/events/president/news/69098) from August. When did Putin stop using very long tables and did he ever explain his decision?

Comment: How do you conclude that Putin stopped using long tables in general from this one example?

Comment: It's clear those *were* the norm in Feb; there are many more photos [here](https://malaysia.news.yahoo.com/photos-putin-keeps-his-distance-during-meetings-194633383.html).

Comment: Apparently there was a huge peak/surge of Covid in Russia from Jan to March (and has been much less this summer), but I'm not sure his personal behavior/decisions are 100% based on that. He claimed to have been vaccinated last fall with multiple boosters https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/coronavirus/putin-tests-experimental-nasal-vaccine-against-covid-19-1.5679341

Comment: But he used it again to meat the head of the UN at the end of April https://news.yahoo.com/putin-breaks-kremlins-ridiculously-long-182324191.html so it's probably not the case he completely stopped using it.

Comment: OTOH he met closely with Bolsonaro in Feb, https://news.sky.com/video/no-long-table-for-brazils-president-as-he-meets-vladimir-putin-in-moscow-12543534 so it's probalby incorrect to conclude there it was based on the time of the meeting.

Comment: @Fizz I think you’re right. I do wonder why he sometimes met his own government officials at the ping table though…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putin [met](https://news.yahoo.com/putin-breaks-kremlins-ridiculously-long-182324191.html) in similar conditions at the end of April with the head of the UN, and at a multi-head meeting in Turkmenistan at the [end of June](https://www.newsweek.com/putin-his-allies-mocked-meeting-absolutely-massive-table-1720473). (This despite that Putin [says](https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/coronavirus/putin-tests-experimental-nasal-vaccine-against-covid-19-1.5679341) he received multiple Covid vaccine boosters, FWTW.) So he *probably* still socially distances the same way (as pictured multiple times [in Feb](https://malaysia.news.yahoo.com/photos-putin-keeps-his-distance-during-meetings-194633383.html)) from those who don't take the Kremlin's strict Covid tests. Those who were meeting said conditions, like Bolsonaro, [met](https://news.sky.com/video/no-long-table-for-brazils-president-as-he-meets-vladimir-putin-in-moscow-12543534) at much closer range, even back in Feb. So the time
the meeting took place appears to have little role here; protocol was apparently the determining factor. I don't know exactly why he met at "long range" with his own power circle back in Feb. I'm guessing that had less to do with them refusing to take all the tests and was rather based on other considerations, which I could not find officially stated. One might guess that the time pressure of the invasion-related meetings made following the strict Covid protocols more difficult. Actually, they did kinda comment on that [too](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20220215-long-shot-putin-s-giant-table-sparks-jokes-and-speculation), apparently they were extra measures for the recently discovered Omicron, then.

> 15/02/2022
>
> On Monday, Foreign Minister Sergei Lavrov and Defence Minister Sergei Shoigu were forced to sit several metres away from Putin as they delivered reports on Ukraine.
>
> Asked about these distancing measures, Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov said Tuesday they were "temporary".
>
> He said they were in place to avoid the highly-contagious and often asymptomatic Omicron variant.
>
> "There is nothing terrible or special here. We are going through times that dictate special measures," Peskov told reporters.

There's [footage](https://www.ruptly.tv/en/videos/20200324-009-Russia-Shoigu-tests-negative-for-COVID-19-upon-arrival-from-Syria) from 2020 of Shoigu getting tested (when returning from Syria), so undoubtedly he wasn't test-shy.

Answer (score 4):

The tables were used in particular context - the Covid pandemics, claimed to be a social distancing measure. While the exaggerated table length was likely a way of destabilizing and ridiculing the negotiation opponents, it is incorrect to suggest that the practice was used before or after the pandemics context.

[Reuters reports:](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/putin-kept-macron-distance-snubbing-covid-demands-sources-2022-02-10/)

> French President Emmanuel Macron refused a Kremlin request that he take a Russian COVID-19 test when he arrived to see President Vladimir Putin this week, to prevent Russia getting hold of Macron's DNA, two sources in Macron's entourage told Reuters.

> As a result, the visiting French head of state was kept at a distance from the Russian leader during lengthy talks on the Ukraine crisis in Moscow.

> They were photographed at opposite ends of a table so long that it provoked satirical comment on social media and speculation, including by diplomats, that Putin might be using it to send a message.

Comment: Did Putin declare the pandemic to be over sometime since June? (That’s when he seems to have last used such a table)

Comment: @JonathanReez see the Reuters article linked. This was widely covered in the media at the time, so your question is really poorly researched (note that I am not downvoting.)

Comment: Reuters implies that Macron sat far away because he refused to take a DNA test but Putin met his own government officials in a similar setting later in the same month: https://youtu.be/hGT78_sKRZc. Did they refuse to get tested too?

Comment: @JonathanReez Why do you think that the official explanation is different? Even if Putin behaves inconsistently about using the long tables, we cannot discuss his motivations - it is against forum rules.

Comment: So is the pandemic over in Russia? Is that what you're saying? Did Putin declare victory over that like Kim Jong Un (or even like Macron did at one point)?

Comment: AFAICT he did do that [in 2020](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/putin-safe-behind-kremlin-walls-declares-victory-over-covid-19-n1231871). Did he do it again this summer?

Comment: @Fizz I said only what I said. Any distortions or conclusions that you draw are of your own making.